# Error with Craft Commerce & Stripe no longer supports API requests made with TLS 1.0

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I am using the code from the example templates to integrate a simple stripe pay button on a commerce site:

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/payments/pay"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/orders/order?number={number}"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="cancelUrl" value="/checkout/payment"/>
  {{ getCsrfInput() }}
  {% if cart.paymentMethod.class == 'Stripe' %}
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
    class="stripe-button"
    data-label="Pay Now"
    data-key="{{ cart.paymentMethod.settings.publishableKey ?? '' }}"
    data-name="{{ siteName }}"
    data-image="/assets/img/tfa-logo-128.png"
    data-description="Membership" {# This is not used for order description in stripe - see Craft Commerce general settings #}
    data-email="{{ cart.email }}"
    data-currency="{{ cart.paymentCurrency }}"
    data-amount="{{ cart.totalPrice|commerceCurrency(cart.paymentCurrency,convert=true,format=false) * 100 }}"
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
  {% endif %}
</form>
```

When the form submits I get back the following error:

> Stripe no longer supports API requests made with TLS 1.0. Please
>   initiate HTTPS connections with TLS 1.2 or later. You can learn more
>   about this at https://stripe.com/blog/upgrading-tls.

Is this something that needs updating in the commerce plugin? I am running my local site using HTTPS using Valet. I found [this link](https://packagist.org/packages/stripe/stripe-php#user-content-ssl--tls-compatibility-issues) which suggests it might be the plugin that needs updating (I am using the latest version of craft commerce).

Comment: Which browser and browser version are you using?

Comment: I’m on the latest version of chrome. I don’t think it’s a browser issue, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with your local install of OpenSSL `curl`/PHP or some other system level component.

Comment: This is the answer but I have no idea how to update Valet to work using TLS 1.2 or later.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using macOS then your cURL is most likely linked against SecureTransport rather than OpenSSL.

To verify you can issue the following command: `php -i | grep "SSL Version"`

If affected, it should return: `SSL Version => SecureTransport`

To fix the issue you need to recompile cURL and PHP linked with OpenSSL.

For PHP 7.1 do this:

```
brew uninstall php71-mcrypt
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies --force php71
brew install --with-openssl curl
brew install --with-homebrew-curl php71
brew install php71-mcrypt
```

Replace 71 with 70 if you're using PHP 7.0